# Parameter Passing using java/jdbc from a JtextField

Tags: java, swing, jdbc

I need to be able to search a derby database by 3 key values. I have a GUI set up and am able to populate it with data from the database. I have it set up so that I can scroll in either direction. The problem I am having is when I created a method to do a specific search of one of the key fields my query fails. The following is the method I am trying to use to facilitate the search. I've tried using statement and concatenating the variable to the String statement and I've tried using a prepared statement and binding the variable. Neither of which I can get to work. I have marked in the code where the error occurs.

```
public static void Search(){
    String idField = InitGUI.getidField().getText();
    String sql = ("SELECT * FROM MYDB.Employee WHERE Employee ID = '"+idField +"'");

    try {

//      prepStat = dbCon.prepareStatement(sql);
//      prepStat.setString(1, idField);
//      rs = prepStat.executeQuery();
    rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);     <== This is where the error occurs.
    SqlStatements.SearchResult(rs.getRow());
    } catch (SQLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The following is the stacktrace.

```
Connected to database
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "ID" at line 1, column 44.
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException(Unknown   Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.ConnectionChild.handleException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
at Scheduler.DBConnector.Search(DBConnector.java:77)
at Scheduler.myActionListener.actionPerformed(myActionListener.java:20)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Syntax error: Encountered "ID" at line 1, column 44.
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
... 46 more
Caused by: ERROR 42X01: Syntax error: Encountered "ID" at line 1, column 44.
at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.ParserImpl.parseStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepMinion(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepare(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.conn.GenericLanguageConnectionContext.prepareInternalStatement(Unknown Source)
... 40 more
```

Comment: a) What error occurs? If you have a stacktrace please add it. b) Is your Employee.ID a string field in your database? If not you may need to convert to Integer (i.e. don't use quotes in your first query or use `preStat.setInteger()` in your alternative approach)

Comment: Please post the output of `e.printStackTrace()`

Comment: Nit Pick - You should be passing the `idField` to the `Search` method.  You should using `PreparedStatement`. You should be following [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html)

Comment: Last time I checked, column names didn't have spaces. `Employee ID` doesn't look right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you forget the `.` between `Employee` and `ID` ?
`"SELECT * FROM MYDB.Employee WHERE Employee.ID = "+idField`

Your stacktrace `Syntax error` means yours sql syntax is wrong. The `Encoutered "ID" at line 1` means the syntaxic analysis fails between `Employee` and `ID`.

If your column names `Employee ID`, escape it with double quote or backquote, depends on your DBMS ;)

Comment: Im new to the whole database thing. It looks as though there is a space in the Employee ID column. Is that not possible ?

Comment: After checking the column , Employee ID does in fact have a space in it. Is this improper ?

Comment: @Keith What database?  You may need to "quote" the column name

Comment: See https://builds.apache.org/job/Derby-docs/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/trunk/out/ref/crefsqlj34834.html#crefsqlj34834 - you need to quote the name with double quotes. Better yet, if possible, rename the column and remove the space. And, use the bind variable approach to avoid SQL injection issues.

Comment: @Keith see my edited answer, as said by Andreas, you need to quote the  name with double quotes or backquote (depends of your DBMS)